# Find <video> tag in newly opened window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I want to cycle trough a list of links and open each of them in a new window and get the  tag in each of them.

So far I have achieved this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            console.log(links[i]);
            var openedWindow = window.open(links[i], '_blank').focus();
            videoList.push(openedWindow.document.querySelectorAll("div video")); //Add the video links in the newly opened video
            openedWindow.close();
}
```

videoList is a global variable

```
const videoList = [];
```

The error I get whenevery I try to run this code in Chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
at grabLinks (<anonymous>:15:45)
at <anonymous>:69:1
```

The error is in this line of code:

```
videoList.push(openedWindow.document.querySelectorAll("div video"));
```

My question is what exactly am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

If you need more information please tell me.

Comment: Is the video page from the same origin as the script page?

Comment: The script domain goes like this: domain.de/uehfuhauhdauwhduwahd.hmtl and the domain of every window that opens goes like this: domain.de/awdiwaiudherufh.html. I will look into web scraping thank you for your help.

Comment: @getmyisland - And they're both using `http:`, or both using `https:`? If so, it's the same origin and the SOP isn't the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder both use https: then the domain with .de and then /auwidhuhwduaw.html only the random letters in the end are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the links are on the same origin as the page where you're running this, you should be able to access the contents of the documents — but you have to wait for those contents to load, which your current code isn't doing. That involves waiting for an event from `openedWindow`, which means the entire process will be asynchronous.

Separately, your current code is grabbing the `video` elements, but you're closing the window that those `video` elements live in. That may well be okay, but from the name `grabLinks` it sounds like you're primarily interested in the [`currentSrc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentSrc) or [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/src) of the `video` elements, so let's grab that.

I'd write a function to do a single window, probably returning a promise:

```
function getVideoSources(link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const openedWindow = window.open(link, "_blank");
        openedWindow.focus();
        openedWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            try {
                const videoElements = openedWindow.document.querySelectorAll("div video");
                const sources = Array.from(videoElements, element => element.currentSrc || element.src);
                resolve(sources);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    openedWindow.close();
                } catch (e2) { } // In an up-to-date browser, you can leave
                                 // the `(e2)` part off
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then `grabLinks` could be an `async` function that works its way through the URLs in series (since the browser won't let you open a bunch of windows all at once, and the `focus()` calls would interfere with each other):

```
async function grabLinks(links) {
    const videoList = [];
    for (const link of links) {
        const sources = await getVideoSources(link);
        videoList.push(...sources);
    }
    return videoList;
}
```

The fulfillment value of the promise from `grabLinks` will be an array of the `currentSrc` or `src` property values from the elements.

**Beware**, though, that this needs to be kicked off by a user action (button click or similar), and the browser may limit how many windows you can open in a row.

Comment: The Browser now tells me that there is an Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener') is this because I'm trying to run this code in the console of my browser (Chrome)?

Comment: @getmyisland - No, it's because `focus()` doesn't have any return value. I'd kept your `const openedWindow = window.open(link, "_blank");`, but that needs to broken up into two statements. I've updated the answer.